# Pass a query inside Where in ()

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a query which is looking like this,

```
select * from tbl1 where field1 in (select field2 from tbl2 where id=1)
```

- where field1 is of type integer
- and `select field2 from tbl2 where id=1` will return '1,2,3' which is a string

Obviously, we cannot pass string in order to check a field which is of type integer.  What I am asking is, How to fix the above query? or Is there any alternate solution for this?

My DBMS : Postgresql 9.0.3

Comment: Do you want to compare against the integer value of the string or do you want to split the value and compare against every separate value in the string?

Comment: '1,2,3' or '1','2','3' ?

Comment: For clarity, could you add an example table definition and data on SQLFiddle?

Comment: @Wolph I need to run the query in my case as same as `select * from tbl1 where field1 in (1,2,3)` but the query which was given by me will evaluate like this `select * from tbl1 where field1 in ('1,2,3')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from tbl1
where field1 in (
    select regexp_split_to_table(field2, ',')::int
    from tbl2
    where id=1
)
```

Variation suggested by **Igor**

```
select *
from tbl1
where field1 = any (
    select regexp_split_to_array(field2, ',')::int[]
    from tbl2
    where id=1
)
```

Comment: Or `field1 = ANY( select regexp_split_to_array(field2, ',')) ...)`

Comment: @Igor ...Or that. Do you think there is any performance difference?

Comment: Havent tested - so cant say that there will be any difference. But `regexp_split_to_table` will create many aditional tuples (one row per number in list) while `regexp_split_to_array` will only create one tuple.

Comment: And another method - `('{'||field2||'}')::int[]` instead of `regexp_split_to_array(field2, ',')::int[]`. Might be faster but is a bit ugly.

Comment: Yes your solution is working fine, Plus one For taught something New.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from tbl1 where cast(field1 as varchar) in (select field2 from tbl2 where id=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first split the input using [regex_split_to_array()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) method and then use those IDs by casting them to integers

Try this -

```
select * from tbl1 where field1 in 
(select NULLIF(x[1],'')::int,NULLIF(x[2],'')::int,NULLIF(x[3],'')::int from 
(select regex_split_to_array(field2) from tbl2 where id=1) as dt(x))
```

Given that you have known number of elements i.e. 3 in this case coming from that result of the second query.